# Issue trying to sub sample an image

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am trying to resize a given image by sub-sampling it. I am using grayscae iamges.

The way I understand sub-sampling is basically this:

Let's say we have an 5x5 image and we want to resize it by a factor of 2, so the output image will be 3x3.

So if the 5x5 is: (1 2 3 4 5; 6 7 8 9 10; 11 12 13 14 15; 16 17 18 19 20; 21 22 23 24 25)

Then the 3x3 will be: (1 3 5; 11 13 15; 21 23 25)

So if the factor is 2, for the first row we take the first sample and then every second sample and so on. The same for columns.

The code that I wrote for this is:

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
for row=1:old_rows
    if mod((row-1), a) == 0
        i = i + 1;
    end
    for col=1:old_cols
        if mod((row-1), a) == 0 && mod((col-1), a) == 0
            j = j + 1;
            sub_sampled_I(i, j) = I(row, col); % I is the input image
        end
    end
    j = 0;
end

sub_sampled_I = im2uint8(sub_sampled_I); 

end
```

The issue is that the final image has nothing to do with the original. It is just a white image with some black points here and there. What I understand wrong about sub-sampling?

Comment: You want to use `I(1:2:end, 1:2:end)` to subsample. Note that your code updates `sub_sampled_I` for each row in the input image, not just for every other row. Note also that `im2uint8` multiplies a double matrix by 255. You might want to initialize `sub_sampled_I` as `uint8` instead.

Comment: The solution was as you said to initialize sub_sampled_I as uint8.  Thank you for your concise answer.